# Is there a way to load MongoDB snappy data file into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I have a dataset which is exported from MongoDB and compressed as snappy file and want to load the data into MySQL.

I have searched a lot but couldn't find a solution. So is there a way to load the snappy data from MongoDB into MySQL?

Comment: How you expect mongo documents to be flattened to sql tables?

Comment: MySQL5.7 supports JSON data type. I think every mongo document could be placed in one field which data type is JSON in MySQL.

Comment: Restore it, then convert to mysql inserts: `echo "insert into test (json) values" > insert.sql; for json in (mongo so --eval 'db.test.find();' | tail -n +4) echo "($json)" >> insert.sql end` ?

Comment: Thanks and I'll try this method :D